# AngularJS inserting new properties to an object using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop, foreach

I need to combine two arrays together. 
In the this code block I'm trying to get each user row from the foo array and make it into a new array.

```
UserService.GetUserFoo(id)
        .success(function (data) {         
         data = angular.fromJson(data); //[{id:1, u_id:1, foo:"a"}{id:2, u_id:2, foo:"b"}]

         angular.forEach(data, function(user){
                getUser(user.u_id)   }); //FUNCTION CALL       
         }).
        error(function(error) {
         //do something       
      });
```

In this code block, the getUser function is called in the GetUserFoo service to populate a new array called $scope.users

```
$scope.users = []; //[{id:1, name:"Ed"},{id:2, name:"Jim"}]
      var getUser = function(id) {
            UserService.GetUserById(id)
            .success(function (data) {
              data = angular.fromJson(data);
                $scope.users.push(data); //                
            }).error(function(error) {
                       //do something
            });
        };
```

QUESTION --> How do insert each foo field into each corresponding $scope.users object so that in my view i can have something like this

```
//[{id:1, name:"Ed", foo:"a"}{id:2, name:"Jim", foo:"b"}]

<li ng-repeat="user in users">
<h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
<p>{{user.foo}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.users=[
        {id:1,name:"user 1"},
        {id:2,name:"user 2"}
    ];
    $scope.fooUser=[
        {id:1,foo:"foo 1"},
        {id:2,foo:"foo 2"}
    ];
    
    $scope.insertProperty=function(){
       
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<$scope.fooUser.length;j++){
                if($scope.users[i].id==$scope.fooUser[j].id)
                    $scope.users[i].foo=$scope.fooUser[j].foo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
             <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>

            <p ng-cloak>{{user.foo}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="insertProperty()">insert property</button>
</div>
```

for this one you dont need to worry about the length and orders of the two arrays

Comment: the logic inside 'insertProperty' function show you how to insert property that you asked. but where to trigger this function really depends on your case. if your getUserData service is an ajax call, you may want to run insertProperty function in the success method of your ajax call

Comment: Perfect thanks, i've inserted in in all the lines i could think of.. i didn't realize it should goin the success method

Answer (score 1):

As long as both array have the same length, and each `id` in the array is in the same position in both array:

```
var array1 = angular.copy($scope.users);
var array2 = angular.copy(data);

$scope.users = mergeArray(array1, array2);

function mergeArray (array1, array2) {
  for (index in array1) {
    angular.extend(array1[index], array2[index]);
  }
  return array1;
}
```